# Linq filter based on null column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, join

```html
DateTime                ChangedBy       ChangedColumn   OldVal  NewVal
08/24/2015 08:50:27 AM  john@test.com   lastname       John     Doe
08/24/2015 08:50:27 AM  john@test.com   lastname       NULL     Doe
08/25/2015 05:40:27 AM  jane@test.com   lastname       Jane     Doe
08/25/2015 05:40:27 AM  jane@test.com   lastname       NULL     Doe
08/25/2015 04:40:27 AM  jane@test.com   lastname       NULL     Doe
```

How to i remove the rows with NULL in OldVal column using linq?
The challenge here is i need the row with (08/25/2015 04:40:27 AM ) also.

Comment: So you need the non null rows AND the row with the earliest DateTime? What's the specification for your query?

Comment: Exactly.My result should contain 1,3 and 5 rows only.

Comment: So if I read to an array and picked out indexes [0, 2, 4] that would work for all similar queries? ;) What's special about row 5 in this example? Is it the fact that it's between 4 and 5 AM?

Comment: I cannot pick index here as rows can change.time is the only difference.

Comment: Edit your question not just the comment. what is the logic begin select the 4:40 am row?

Comment: But what's special about that row's time? If you order by `DateTime` it's the middle value? It's the only one whose hour is 4?

Comment: old value cannot also NULL. Here the first row with unique time should be included as it a special event happens in different time

Comment: old value mean oldest value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
var minValue = aList.Min(row => x.DateTime);
aList = aList.Where(row => row.OldVal != NULL 
                        || row.DateTime == minValue)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: old value cannot also NULL. Here the first row with unique time should be included as it a special event happens in different time

Comment: Fix to include the min(DateTime) row

Comment: Please remember upvote my answer if that help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var specialRow = table.Where(row => IsSpecial(row.DateTime));
var result = (from row in table
             where row.OldVal.HasValue
             select row)
        .Union(specialRow);
```

Comment: ok. They all are events happen in that order. Cannot do a union here.